What film or show has side characters dressed in blue overalls and skullcaps?
I'm trying to track down a live-action sci-fi TV show or possibly film that had some characters - I think they were cleaners - who wore blue overalls and skullcaps.  I think there were two of them, and one of them had black curly hair.  Their uniform looked a lot like that of Stanley Tweedle from Lexx, but blue instead of red.  They were side characters, but it's possible that they were the main characters for their one episode, but not the main characters overall - a bit like Bo and Mack in Babylon 5's A View from the Gallery.

https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/Lower_Deck_Episode#Live-Action_TV

Yes, that sort of thing exactly - I think!  I don't see any obvious matches in that list, but I'll keep looking.  Thanks!

Andor? Syril and Linus wear blue uniforms with skullcaps https://i.sstatic.net/aZTfS.png

Afraid not - those hats have peaks, whereas the ones I'm thinking of had a band around the bottom but no peaks.

Possibly Bo and Mack from the Babylon 5 Episode "A View from the Gallery". https://neatnik2009.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/babylon-5-a-view-from-the-gallery-1998/

I did wonder about them - I even mention them in the OP - but I couldn’t find any shots where they were wearing hats like that.
